# Android : which is the best way to periodically call a function?

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, android-handler

I have to do a particolar function one time Every 2 seconds, and I have to stop it when a certain broadcast message arrive then I have to restart it when other message arrives. I use handler postdelayed(runnable,time) and inside the runnable function i have called postdelayed(this,2000). But i can't stop it.. And when I restart the runnable I have different runnable started at the same time. 
I call handler.removecallback

Comment: You can switch over to `Handler` and schedule `Message` instead of `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks ! I have to search how i can use it  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AlarmManager` for scheduling repeat events, you can cancel the alarm using the `cancel()` method.

E.g. `alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);`

Comment: 2 seconds is not optimal timeout for using AlarmManager. Too much overhead for a function that called only when app is running.